# Migration from Moss 2007 to 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, migration

A client has medium size MOSS 2007 application with 250 sites. Now they wants to migrate from MOSS 2007 to 2013. As far as I know direct migration is not possible. but if we wants to take it to 2013 from 2007 what are the steps we should think & follow.

How to convince client that direct migration is not possible (2007 to 2013). How do you handle this situation?

What is the best possible way?

Which one is correct way? 3rd party tools or direct one? For 250 sites which one we should follow?

For 2010 to 2013 migration for 250 sites application with good amount of custom code which approach will be better? DB attach?

Can we directly migrate to SP 2013 Online from 2010? What are the prerequisites?

Answer (score 2):

On upgrading from 2007 to 2013, try this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee947141(v=office.15)

It covers both why two upgrades are required as well as how you would go about it.

The "best way" depends on your infrastructure really. Personally I've always preferred a brand new farm installation, installing any custom / 3rd party solutions and then attaching the content databases.

In terms of SharePoint Online, if you have custom code then you would need to rework that into the new 2013 app model before you'll be able to migrate to SharePoint online.